# Conditional print button with inputs

Tags: excel

I would like to print n number of labels in excel that all follow a template given in a print area. The great issue is, could i make these labels get numbers 1,2,3,4....n AND could i make them start at x instead of 1. For example print from input x=140 to y=x+n and i would input n=60 Number of labels(or input y), with first label having number 140, same batch info, same Best before info but the 60 printed labels get numbered 140-199. I hope this made sense, because I am quite lost. [Templeate example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdZ5G.png)

I Tried creating a print button of the area, but I am Completely lost when it comes to making this function input numbers into the template that should be printed. I suppose the labels could be generated 1-n and then print those(Don't know how to, I just know it is possible).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.